# xpath-function max doesn't work

Tags: xslt

For unknown reason max function doesn't work.

XML input file:

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<numbers>
    <number>3</number>
    <number>5</number>
    <number>10</number>
    <number>1</number>
</numbers>
```

XSL input file

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/numbers">
        <numbers>       
            <xsl:value-of select="/numbers/number" />                   

            fn:max(2, 3)

        </numbers>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<numbers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions">3                   

            fn:max(2, 3)


        </numbers>
```

Input file is not important here, but I would like to have '3' instead of fn:max(2, 3). How to do it?

for this XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/numbers">
        <numbers>       
            <xsl:value-of select="/numbers/number" />                   

            fn:max(2, 3)
            <xsl:value-of select="max(/numbers/number)"/>

        </numbers>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the following error occurs:

SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #49; Could not find function: max
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #49; function token not found.
(Location of error unknown)java.lang.NullPointerException

(Location of error unknown)XSLT Error (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException)
: No xml-stylesheet PI found in: test.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No xml-stylesheet PI foun
d in: test.xml
        at org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.doExit(Process.java:1155)
        at org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.main(Process.java:1128)

I used Xalan - Version Xalan Java 2.7.1, Command: java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in test.xml -xsl test.xsl -out output.xml

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems: max() needs to be in a value-of, and that you've said `xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"` for Xalan, which only supports XSLT **1.0**.  For 2.0, you'd need Saxon 9.x.

Since max() isn't part of XSLT 1.0, you need to invoke the [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/howto.html) extension support, which Xalan does have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
    <xsl:template match="/numbers">
        <xsl:value-of select="math:max(number)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="math:max(numbers/number)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've put `fn:max(2,3)` in a text block. Nothing is going to interpret that. You need to put functions in `value-of` expressions if you want them to be evaluated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

 <xsl:value-of select="max(/numbers/number)"/>

it's not working

Comment: I mean <xsl:value-of select="fn:max(2,3)"/>

Comment: Actually `<xsl:value-of select="fn:max((2,3))"/>` - the function takes a single argument which is a sequence of numbers; it can't be called with two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Lavino,

Thanks for the response. I don't know why but I was pretty sure that Xalan supports 2.0... I've tested it and it works for Saxon 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="max(number)" />
```

to get the max of all numbers.

Soln:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/numbers">
        <numbers>
            <max>
                <xsl:value-of select="max(number)"/>
            </max>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </numbers>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="number">
        <number>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </number>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can omit the number template and `<xsl:apply-templates/>` if its not reqd. This will be the output with the above xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<numbers xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <max>10</max>
    <number>3</number>
    <number>5</number>
    <number>10</number>
    <number>1</number>
</numbers>
```